# BETWEEN clause using two tables takes more time to complete the query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables.

> **ip_address_tables** *( ip_address NUMBER)*;

50000  - IP addresses decimal valuve

> **country_ip_range**
>
> ( BEGINIPNUM *NUMBER*, ENDIPNUM   *NUMBER*, COUNTRYCODE *VARCHAR2(50)* );

20 lacks record.

Using IP address I am trying to find the country code. It takes more time like 1 hour.

```
 SELECT cip.* 
 FROM   ip_address_tables b
 ,      country_ip_range  cip
 WHERE  b.ip_address >=  cip.beginipnum 
 AND    b.ip_address <=  cip.endipnum
```

Could someone help to run the query very quickly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try creating an index on ip_address, beginipnum and endipnum...

Comment: Run an explain plan first.  See if there is a full table scan going on.  HOw many records are we talking about for each table?

Comment: I have created an index on both tables and tried. Even though it was very slow. full table scan/ index both are very slow. It going as merge join.

Comment: Please post the explain plan here.

Comment: An index on ip_address_tables.ip_address won't help since it will have to execute a full table scan anyway.

Comment: BTW: use an explicit join: `FROM ip_address_tables b JOIN country_ip_range cip ON b.ip_address BETWEEN cip.beginipnum AND cip.endipnum`